# How to prepare insert statement from select statement of snowflake query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to prepare insert statement from the output of snowflake query.

In simple words, I have few rows as the output of a snowflake query and I want to prepare the insert statment from that output result. Is there any way in snowflake?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest thing is insert select, there are some good examples here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#multi-row-insert-using-query

other than that (if you want to just prepare the statement and not execute it) the way to go would be stored procedures:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#dynamically-creating-a-sql-statement - just have your procedure return that statement you want built instead of execute it and return result